# What does Jaime Lannister say he wants at the beginning of season four?

Tags: dialogue, game-of-thrones

Right at the beginning of Season 4 of Games of Thrones Jaime Lannister has an meeting with his father, Tywin Lannister, in which his father gives him a sword of "Valerian steel" and tells him to assume the lordship of Casterly Rock. Jaime refuses this order and says he does not want Casterly Rock. Tywin then asks "What do you want?" and Jaimee answers "???? would be nice". I can't understand what he said though. What would be nice?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The dialogue is:

> **Jaime:** I don't want Casterly Rock, I don't want a wife, I don't want children!
>   **Tywin:** What do you want?
>   **Jaime:** Supper would be nice.

It's a nonchalant remark in a show of defiance to his father. He's not going to play his *game*, answering questions about his future. He has already made up his mind about what he wants - to stay in the Kingsguard.

Comment: It demonstrates that Tywin has great ambitions for himself and his family, but Jaime is satisfied with the status quo at that moment.